# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flip is not a function in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using a third party plugin and now I want to add a flip effect. I have included the flip.js to the plugin. I am able to call the flip.js library, but when I am trying to call the function inside a function  it is throwing me an error.

Please see the steps below:

step 1) including the flip.js:

```
public function enqueue_scripts() {
//for flip effect
                wp_enqueue_script('cookie-flip-effect', CTCC_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js/jquery.flip.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

//plugin js
                wp_enqueue_script('cookie-consent', CTCC_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js/uk-cookie-consent-js.js', array('jquery'), '2.3.0', true);
}
```

step 2: calling the flip function : This is called from uk-cookie-consent-js.js

```
function closeHT() {
    $("#catapult-cookie-bar").flip({
        axis: 'x',
        trigger: 'click'
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the text of your error message?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $("#catapult-cookie-bar").flip is not a function

Comment: Check if the plugin is included before the uk-cookie-consent-js.js. View the page source and see if the plugin script comes before uk-cookie-consent-js.js.

Comment: @Dan Philip plugin is uk-cookie. I copied the flip.js into the plugin